# How do you connect to a UCP in SQL Server Management Studio 17.1

Tags: ssms

I recently upgraded to SQL Server Management Studio 17.1  I cannot find a menu option to connect to a UCP like the 2016 versions had.  Does anyone know where they moved this functionality?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this a microsoft issue, a bug report has been filed.  Utility Explorer is not currently a menu option in SSMS 17.

[SQL Server Utility Explorer Missing from SSMS 17.0](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/3134389/sql-server-utility-explorer-missing-from-ssms-v17-0)

Comment: It's not missing, it has been removed according to [SSMS 17 change log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-changelog-ssms).